# Nice result using Bernoulli variables?

Tags: probability, reference-request, probability-distributions

I'm preparing an oral exam concerning independant Bernoulli variables sequences. I have to present two 'big' results concerning those, and each result must take more or less 15' of demonstration.

Problem is I'm not so interested in probabilities, so I'd like to find results that are also used in other areas (algebra preferably!). For instance, my first demonstration will concern Bernstein's polynomials.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend choosing one of the famous results on Binomial distributions. Remember that Binomial RVs are just IID sums of Bernoulli RVs.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Related_distributions

In particular you can talk about the Wierstrass approximation theorem using Bernstein polynomials, or the normal or poisson approximations.

Namely if $n \to \infty, p \to 0$ in  such a way that $np \to \lambda > 0$, then $\text{Binomial}(n,p) \to \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ in distribution, or if $n \to \infty$ and $p$ remains fixed, then
$$
\frac{X-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \to \text{Normal}(0,1)
$$
in distribution, where $X$ is a $\text{Binomial}(n,p)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I mentionned, I've already thought of Bernstein polynomials. The normal or poisson approximations could be a good idea if I find nothing else, but I'd like to find something that is less probabity-restricted, if it exists!

Comment: I guess I don't quite understand what you are asking for. You want to talk about Bernoulli random variables without talking about probability?

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear. I'd like a result which uses Bernoulli/binomial variables, but which is useful in other areas that probability. Bernstein polynomials are the perfect example : Bernoulli variables used to approximate a continuous function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's "big" enough, but one neat trick is generating a random variable with a [Cantor distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution) (i.e. its CDF is the Cantor "devil's staircase", and it is continuous but singular):

$$X = 2 \sum_{j=1}^\infty 3^{-j} B_j $$

where $B_j$ are independent Bernoulli$-1/2$ random variables.
You even get to bring in another Bernoulli, if you compute the cumulants of this distribution.

But if you want something related to combinatorics, consider
$$S_n = \sum_{j=1}^n k B_k$$
Its probability mass function
$$ \mathbb P(S_n = m) =  \dfrac{f_n(m)}{2^n}$$ where
$f_n(m)$ is the number of partitions of $m$ into distinct parts that are all $\le n$.